# How to open the index tree content of a .chm file in the wpf application using the webbrowser?

Tags: wpf, chm

I am creating a helpbar for my application and having two things to get done :

1. To provide the online help from the website and display it in a window using webbrowser which i am done with.
2. now in the same browser i want to open the index tree of the .chm file .

so is it possible to open the index tree of the .chm file?

```
browser.Navigate(@"mk:@MSITStore:[my .chm file url]");
```

I am doing this to open a particular content , but i want the starting index tree which is displayed at the left panel of the default help viewer application provided by the microsoft.

Want to know whether it is possible else any suggestions how to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

The CHM index isn't an HTML page — it's stored as binary data in the CHM file. So it can't be displayed in a WebBrowser.

I'd recommend using unpacked HTML help if you need to display the help in a WebBrowser inside the app.